# returning specified type for a linq query with anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, anonymous-types

i have this query:

```
DbQuery<Logs> logs = context.GetQuery<Logs>();
var MessageLogs =
    logs.Where(
        s =>
            s.DATE == date.Date
        .GroupBy(s => new {s.DATE, s.ID})
        .Select(
            g => new {Date = g.Key.DATE, SID = g.Key.ID, Count = g.Count()})
        .GroupBy(x => x.SID, x => new {x.Date, x.Count});
```

and I have these two classess:

```
public class Data
{
    public Values[] Val { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

and this:

```
public class Values
{
    public string type1 { get; set; }
    public string type2 { get; set; }
}
```

all i want to do is using that query to return type of Data. 
key in class Data is SID and list of values should be counts and date as type1 and type2.
i know i can do this with anonymous type but i dont know how, i tried many ways but all of them was wrong.

```
 EDIT:
```

i have this query

```
    logs.Where(
        s =>
            s.DATE == date.Date
        .GroupBy(s => new {s.DATE, s.ID})
        .Select(
            g => new {Date = g.Key.DATE, SID = g.Key.ID, Count = g.Count()})
```

this query returns something like this:

```
 key   date      count
----------------------------
1021   2012        1
1021   2013       5
1022   2001        10
1023   2002        14
```

what i want is base on each id a list of values
in fact return type should be type of Data which this ids are key fore example

```
key=1021 and Values[] should be type1=2012, type2=1 and type1=2013, type2=5
```

Comment: That LINQ query wouldn't compile... it's not really clear to me what you're trying to achieve, at the moment... why are you grouping by date when you've already filtered by date?

Comment: @JonSkeet i tried to make it more clear

Comment: You still haven't fixed the query so that it would compile... you've now got the same broken query twice. The existing query is fairly irrelevant, to be honest - all that's important is the shape of the output.

Comment: If you fail to write lamba query can you manage to write linq or plain sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your current query returns elements with key/date/count, it sounds like you probably just want:

```
var result = query.GroupBy(
    x => x.Key,
    (key, rows) => new Data {
       Key = key,
       Val = rows.Select(r => new Values { type1 = r.Date, type2 = r.Count })
                 .ToArray();
    });
```

Basically [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549393) takes:

- A source
- A key selector
- A transformation from a key and matching rows to a result element (an instance of `Data` in your case)